# Вывести индекс элемента массива по его значению

Tags: php

Прошу желающих и кто в курсе поделиться идеями реализации на этот счет. Единственное до чего за последние 15 минут додумался мой уставший мозг

```
$a = array('John', 'Brad');
$b = array('Doe', 'Born');

if(in_array('John', $a))
{
    foreach($a as $k => $v)
    {
        if($v == 'John')
        {
            echo $b[$k];
        }
    }
}
```

и честно говоря мало вдохновляет на успешную быструю работу.

Кратко говоря нужно вытащить индекс из массива `$a`, передать в масив `$b` и вывести результат. `$b[$k];`

Comment: а как вы думаете, что сделает библиотечная функция? то же самое. если вам надо эффективно искать по значению, у вас не та структура данных.

Comment: **Всем спасибо, обошелся своим костылком) несколько упрощеным.**

Comment: Всем по +1

Answer (score 2):

> array_search()

возвращает индекс массива

> in_array()

проверяет только наличие значения в массиве.

Т.е. для вас подойдет именно array_search()

Comment: array_search() не вернет 0 на сколько я знаю

Comment: если верить документации в случае неудачи array_search возвращает либо NULL, либо FALSE. В любом другом случае индекс элемента

Answer (score 2):

Функция key() тоже должна подойти

Comment: Подошла бы, если бы был нужен ключ. А нужен индекс)

Comment: Ну просто в примерах ассоциативные массивы, вот я и подумал)

Answer (score 2):

Если еще актуально, вот мой костыль:

```
$a = array('John', 'Brad');
$b = array('Doe', 'Born');

$flip = array_flip($a);
echo (isset($b[$flip['John']])) ? $b[$flip['John']] : '';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = array('John', 'Brad');
$b = array('Doe', 'Born');

if (($idx = array_search('John', $a, true)) !== false) {
    echo isset($b[$idx]) ? $b[$idx] : '';
}
```